# JNDI lookup failed for the resource Type: javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: java, postgresql, glassfish

The error is in the title. It's very strange, because I was doing some modifications to the xhtml code and its beans, turning the glassfish server on and off and on again several times, and suddenly this error appeared. I did not touch the web.xml or any of those types of files while I was working, just the xhtml and its beans.

Error message:

```
Severe:   JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: JPATestPU, Lookup: java:app/jpaDB, Type: javax.sql.DataSource.
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [JPAAdvanced]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing

org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [JPATestPU], Lookup: [java:app/jpaDB], Type: [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at[...]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:app/jpaDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation ]
    at[...]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation 
    at[...]

Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [JPAAdvanced] : JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [JPATestPU], Lookup: [java:app/jpaDB], Type: [javax.sql.DataSource]
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:app/jpaDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation ]
    at[...]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation 
    at[...]
```

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The glasfish-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="post-gre-sql_jpaDB_postgresPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">

        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="5432"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="jpaDB"/>
        <property name="User" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="Password" value="*****"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jpaDB"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/jpaDB" object-type="user" pool-name="post-gre-sql_jpaDB_postgresPool"/>
</resources>
```

If there is anything else to add, please say so and I will add it.

Comment: You have created the resource and the pool that indicates there in the log? Does the pool ping?

Comment: @GermanBurgardt to be completely honest, I dont know many technical terms or how much of that works. I don't know what to do :(

Comment: In the glassfish console you have to create a JDBC connection pool to the database. Apparently the error indicates that the connection pool can not be found

Comment: @GermanBurgardt Ive been testing around and found out something. I use netbeans, so opening the services window, going to servers->glassfish->applications, and just undeploying the projects and then running them again seem to fix the issue. But every now and then the error comes again, so i gotta undeply them. Is there a more permanent solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I removed the eclipse jar file in netbeans. Click the eclipse jar file under libraries and click remove.
Then Right on Libraries, choose add Jar and provide the location of the Eclipse jar file.

After try deploy you project it shall work